# Rails: request.subdomains raises undef method for request when in application controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdomain

I am trying to extract the subdomain in the application controller, for app wide use, this way,

```
@subdomain = request.subdomains(0)
```

While this code works in any other controller, in the app controller it throws an

```
undefined local variable or method `request' for ApplicationController:Class
```

exception.

I am running rails 3.2.2 on Lion.

I borrowed it from DHH's code fragment for basecamp style subdomains -

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_current_account
  private
    def set_current_account
      @current_account = Account.find_by_subdomain!(request.subdomains.first)
    end
end
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please format your code using four-space indentation.

Answer (score 3):

When you're getting that error, it's happenning becaue you're calling `request` inside `ApplicationController`'s class instead of inside a method. Are you sure that the code you've shown us is correct?

Comment: That did it Ryan. I added the private method just as in DHH's code. I was indeed calling request inside the class. Thank you very much.

Comment: I was using `request.xhr?` in `before_filter`. Thanks Ryan.